# `npm ERR! code EACCES` from `npx create-react-app front_end --template typescript`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am trying to run the following command in VScode while using WSL-ubuntu:

```
npx create-react-app front_end --template typescript
```

But I get this error message:

```
Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /mnt/c/Users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@types/node
npm ERR! dest /mnt/c/Users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@types/.node-GHmM5nSq
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/c/Users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@types/node' -> '/mnt/c/Users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@types/.node-GHmM5nSq'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/c/Users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@types/node' -> '/mnt/c/Users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@types/.node-GHmM5nSq'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/mnt/c/Users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@types/node',
npm ERR!   dest: '/mnt/c/Users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@types/.node-GHmM5nSq'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-03-12T12_31_21_261Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^12.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 @types/jest@^27.0.1 @types/node@^16.7.13 @types/react@^17.0.20 @types/react-dom@^17.0.9 typescript@^4.4.2 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: try using sudo like `npx create-react-app front_end --template typescript` or try to open WSL as admin

Comment: I did that but it did not work.

Comment: sorry had a typo, I meant `sudo npx create-react-app front_end --template typescript`

Comment: This looks like it's related to permissioning issues. Or maybe... could you try renaming that path it's asking you to rename?

Comment: I fixed it by updating npm. However, now that npm is on another version, ganachi-cli stopped working. Switched 1 problem for another.